# How to align watermark in an image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to add multiple watermarks to an image with some gap in between. I have been able to achieve this with two small caveats though.

What I want is:

1. Watermark should be vertically center aligned.
2. The program need to stop adding watermark when there is no sufficient width and/or height left in the image (so that there is no cutting of text).

My code is:

```
static void WatermarkedImage(string path, string fileName, string message, string destFileName)
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path + fileName))
            {
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                Font font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
                SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 0, 0));
                
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

                int index = 0;
                float offsetX = image.Width / 3;
                float offsetY = image.Height / 3;
                int increment = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height * 0.15);

                while (offsetY * 1.25 < image.Height)
                {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.Translate(offsetX, offsetY);
                    matrix.Rotate(-45.0f);

                    graphics.Transform = matrix;
                    graphics.DrawString(message, font, brush, 0, 50, format);

                    offsetX += increment;
                    offsetY += increment;
                    index++;
                }
                image.Save(path + destFileName);
            }
        }
```

This is what I'm getting with this:

[image: Resu]

Desired Output.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank You!

**Update-1**

[image: Update-1]

Comment: I've removed your ASP.NET tag because this question is about image processing and not about ASP.NET (the web framework).

Comment: When you say "_should be aligned at the end_" you mean vertical aligned, right?

Comment: @Cleptus Yes, I mean vertically aligned text. Please see desired output at the end as well. Thanks.

Comment: In your loop you are adding `offsetX += increment;`. That is causing the movement to the right. Try commenting that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output does not have any offset on the x-axis, so you shouldn't increment x offset at all.

```
                    offsetY += increment;
                    index++;
                }
                while (offsetY * 1.25 < image.Height);
                image.Save(path + destFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you @George. This fixed one of the problems. However, I'm still having trouble with the second one, i.e. "The program need to stop adding watermark when there is no sufficient width and/or height left in the image (so that there is no cutting of text)." I added the updated output, please have a look.

Comment: @Ashar Have you tried using while loop? Right now you are using do-while, meaning you first translate the text, then check if it is outside of the page.

Comment: Using a while loop made no difference (Code Updated). The output came out to be the same in both the cases.

Comment: So the text stopping does work, the problem is that the condition only checks if the middle of the text is inside the screen. When you rotate the text, some of it exits the screen. You have to test if offset plus half of text width is outside of the screen. Something like `while (offsetY * 1.25 + textWidth/2 < image.Height);`.  Like JonasH's answer says, you can use MeasureString to find that textWidth.

Answer (score 2):

To check if all of the text is inside the image, use [MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=net-5.0) to see how large the string will be. From this you can construct a rectangle, transform each corner of said rectangle using the matrix, and check if they are all inside the image.